# Loop Array to Plot Marker

Tags: java, arrays, json, loops, dictionary

I have a JSON with an array of 3 objects. So when I retrieveEventJSON(), I am simply setting the attributes to an Event object. And when I call the plotEventOnMap() from another activity, I expect to see 3 markers on the map.

```
public void retrieveEventJSON() throws JSONException {
    String page;
    JSONArray jsonArray;

    try {
        // Code to retrieve data from servlet
        try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(page);
            jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("Events");
            int length = jsonArray.length();
            for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                JSONObject attribute = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                String eventID = attribute.getString("eventID");
                String eventName = attribute.getString("eventName");
                String eventDesc = attribute.getString("eventDesc");
                String eventDate = attribute.getString("eventDate");

                eventModel.setEventID(eventID);
                eventModel.setEventName(eventName);
                eventModel.setEventDesc(eventDesc);
                eventModel.setEventDate(eventDate);

            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void plotEventOnMap(Context context) {
    graphicIcon = new PictureMarkerSymbol(res);
    Point p = new Point(Double.parseDouble(eventModel.getEventX()),
            Double.parseDouble(eventModel.getEventY()));
    Symbol symbol = graphicIcon;

    HashMap<String, Object> attrMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    attrMap.put("eventName", eventModel.getEventName());
    attrMap.put("eventBy", eventModel.getEventBy());

    ENeighbourhoodActivity.graphicsLayer.addGraphic(new Graphic(p, symbol,
            attrMap));
}
```

But with these codes, it just display the last row of record in my JSON instead of looping and plot each of them. Any guides?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How eventModel is defined? I think that there is only one instance of this object so the last one object from json array wins and that's why it just displays the last row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call `.plotEventOnMap()`, or otherwise do something with the `EventModel` you've constructed, from inside your loop, after setting all the `EventModel` properties. At the moment, you're just overwriting your `EventModel` without ever using it.

```
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    JSONObject attribute = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
    String eventID = attribute.getString("eventID");
    String eventName = attribute.getString("eventName");
    String eventDesc = attribute.getString("eventDesc");
    String eventDate = attribute.getString("eventDate");

    eventModel.setEventID(eventID);
    eventModel.setEventName(eventName);
    eventModel.setEventDesc(eventDesc);
    eventModel.setEventDate(eventDate);
}
```

Just before the loop ends, you need to do something with the `EventModel` you've now constructed. This might be plotting it, or adding it to some collection, or whatever. But at the moment, you're going straight back into the loop, and then in the next iteration, overwriting all the good work you've done. The reason you're only ending up with the last one is that when you've done the last iteration, what's left in `eventModel` is what you wrote the last time you went through the loop.

In fact I think you also want

```
EventModel eventModel = new EventModel();
```

as the first thing inside your loop. (I don't know if this is exactly right because we haven't seen the code for `EventModel` so I don't know what the constructor looks like.) If you want to keep a `List` (or similar) of all of them, you need to make sure they're all different instances.

I would suggest recasting like this:

```
List<EventModel> events = new ArrayList<EventModel>();     //NEW
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    EventModel eventModel = new EventModel();              //NEW
    JSONObject attribute = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
    String eventID = attribute.getString("eventID");
    String eventName = attribute.getString("eventName");
    String eventDesc = attribute.getString("eventDesc");
    String eventDate = attribute.getString("eventDate");

    eventModel.setEventID(eventID);
    eventModel.setEventName(eventName);
    eventModel.setEventDesc(eventDesc);
    eventModel.setEventDate(eventDate);
    events.add(eventModel);                                //NEW
}
```

After the loop has finished, you'll have a list of `EventModel`s that you can send to your plotting method or whatever's appropriate.

Comment: Because the retrieveEventJSON will execute in background but not the plotting marker on map. So I was thinking if I should declare another Event array to store the Event object. then inside the plot(), I then loop the Event array

Answer (score 0):

`eventModel.setEventName(eventName);` returns the latest element added to it because on every iteration you are resetting it.

You may add the object to the list after each iteration so that the list will have the elements. Declare the your `EventModel` object inside the for loop to have the instance for every iteration.

```
           for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                JSONObject attribute = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                String eventID = attribute.getString("eventID");
                String eventName = attribute.getString("eventName");

              EventModel eventModel=new eventModel();
                eventModel.setEventID(eventID);
                eventModel.setEventName(eventName);

               list.add(eventModel);
            }
```